# Interfax developer account configuration for multiple recipients

Tags: send, fax, interfax

I want to configure an interfax account for sending and receiving faxes.

Can anyone tell me how to send/receive a test fax?

I know about the `.sendFax()` and `.GetList()` methods, but how do I send fax to myself (in test account)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I followed the article,

[Receive incoming faxes via callback to a web application](http://www.interfax.net/en/node/698)

it works fine. But it only gives you intimation that you have received fax.

Edit:

You can set feedback url and use the parameter which they asked. When interfax will receive fax for you, it will send it to your feedback url and it will go directly to your database (If you set this in page load event).

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code

```
MessageItem[] faxList = null;
                Inbound inbound = new Inbound();
                ListType messageListType = ListType.NewMessages;
                int interFaxResult = inbound.GetList(AppConfig.InterfaxUsername, AppConfig.InterfaxPassword, messageListType, AppConfig.InterfaxMaxitems, ref faxList);
                if (interFaxResult == 0)
                {
                   // Save faxes in DB
                }
```